# Spring boot cannot find index.html under resoures folder

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, spring-boot, static-content

folder structure:

[image]

I'm unable to reach test.html which is under resources/static folder:

```
src-> main-> java-> resources -> static -> test.html
```

http://localhost:8080/test.html   (not working)

but able to reach index.html under:

```
src-> main-> java-> webapp-> index.html
```

http://localhost:8080/index.html (working)

from Spring Boot docs, it seems that I supposed to put all of my static content under /src/main/resources/static

extra info: `<packaging>war</packaging>`

WEB-INF inside the war file:

[image]

any idea why I'm not able to reach test.html?

Comment: Move `test.html` from `public` to `static`. If using ThymeLeaf, move it to `src/main/resource/templates` instead.

Comment: Are the java and maven tags relevant here?

Comment: Hi I moved it to static folder, but still getting 404.

Comment: I have exactly he same problem, except I get a 403 Forbidden, not 404.

Answer (score 2):

You must add file extension: "index.html".
Another option (if you want to make it work without extension) is
adding thymeleaf dependency to pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually place the content in a folder named static.

The hierarchy would be src/main/resources/static/index.html

Comment: Hi I moved it to static folder, but still getting 404

Answer (score 0):

Now you want to keep your *resources* into the resource folder which IS NOT in the

`src-> main-> java`

By default Spring-boot is searching for the *.html* files uder that directory :

```
src-> main-> resources-> templates
```

As I can see you are saying that you put yours into the :

```
src-> main-> JAVA-> resources
```

Which is wrong.

Simple :

[image]

Keep your Controllers, Services, Repositories and so on into the `java` folder and keep your resources into the `resources` one. Where you can have a `static` folder for *css, fonts, img, js* and a `templates` folder where you should keep your *htmls*.

Comment: Hi Thanks, but this is not the case. I put under src->main->java my java classes and using jersey without spring-mvc. I've also tried to put my .html file under src-> main -> resources -> templates, but still getting 404. I can access my .html files only under webapp folder.